# Example where $F$ is not continuous on the closed unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the unit circle ${\partial D}=z:|z|=1$. Define $$F(z)=\begin{cases} f(z),&\text{if}|z|=1\\\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw, &\text{if} |z|<1 \end{cases}$$

Find an example where $F(z)$ is not continuous on the closed unit disk $D(0,1)={z:|z|\leq1}$

Hint from professor: let $f(z)=\bar{z}$

I just started complex analysis and have no idea how to do this question so I would really appreciate it if anyone can provide a solution.

Comment: You have stated an incorrect result. Of course $F$ can be continuous on the closed disc. Just take $f\equiv 0.$  What you need to do is edit this to a correct result, saying $F$ need not be continuous.

Comment: @zhw my prof said $F$ is not continuous and i need to take $f(z)=\bar{z}$. i was thinking the continuity depends on $f(z)$ and my professor wants an example of when $F(z)$ is not continuous and show why its is not continuous. is there any way you can provide a solution using $f(z)=\bar{z}$?

Comment: I 'm saying you have stated the problem incorrectly. I doubt your prof said $F$ is always discontinuous.

Comment: if i assume $f(z)=\bar{z}$. how would i do this question?

Comment: I edited your question. I hope you can understand why I did so. Now your professor says to try $f(z)=\bar z.$ What happened when you tried that?

Comment: @zhw thks for the edit. if i say $f(z)=\bar{z}$ then $F(z)=\bar{z}$ for $|z|=1$. but i dont understand what will happen for $|z|<1$. i m not sure how to handle the integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $f(z)=\bar z.$ Note that if $z=e^{it},$ then $\bar z = e^{-it}.$ Thus for $|z|<1,$

$$F(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{-it}\cdot ie^{it}}{e^{it} - z}\,dt.$$

Comment: now to solve the integral do i put $z=1$ ?

Comment: No, $|z|<1.$  You can solve this integral by thinking about geometric series.

Comment: i havent studied geometric series. can you please solve this for me?